# Access custom view column from exchange public folder

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using Exchange Web Services to access contact records in a public folder.  I need to pull a custom column, "Client Contact Management", created for a view in that folder.  The custom column was created in the user interface.

I've already used the `ExtendedPropertyDefinition` class before on properties that I have created on my own through code.  Is that what I'm supposed to use in this case and if so then how do I get the guid for the custom column?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer on this [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/b5e9f29e-7b89-4fe9-83db-8f167c5eb7e9) from David Sterling on the microsoft exchange server forums.  His example (copied below) shows how to do things using EWS directly and using the managed api.

```
// via autogenerated proxy classes

PathToExtendedFieldType hairColorPath = new PathToExtendedFieldType();
hairColorPath.DistinguishedPropertySetId = DistinguishedPropertySetType.PublicStrings;
hairColorPath.DistinguishedPropertySetIdSpecified = true;
hairColorPath.PropertyName = "HairColor";
hairColorPath.PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.String;

// via the Client API

ExtendedPropertyDefinition hairColor = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
      DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, 
      "HairColor", 
      MapiPropertyType.String);
```

Here is what I did using the managed api for my own problem.  The key is using the `DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings` which is where outlook stores the custom view column.

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition _clientContactManagementPropertyDefinition =
     new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
          DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, 
          "Client Contact Management", 
          MapiPropertyType.Boolean
);
```